# Show DateTime with timezone offset in xml response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have a .amsx Web Service, which has following method
[WebMethod]

```
public SalesList GetAgentSalesDetail()
{ .....
}
```

It returns me xml response like this.

```
<Sales>
<SaleInfo>
<SaleID>71076</SaleID>
<SaleDate>2014-03-03T18:22:54</SaleDate>
<PricePaid>9.99</PricePaid>
</SaleInfo>
</Sales>
```

My server's time zone is CST and I have DateTime Property of SaleDate. The question is how can I show the timestamp including time zone offset so instead of "2014-03-03T18:22:54" , I want to show 
"2014-03-03T18:22:54-05:00".

Comment: what is the `Kind` property of your `SaleDate` property? try changing this to `Local` if pulling the results from a db (which will be unspecified)

Comment: it is a DateTime variable in Class and timestamp is the data type in DB.

Comment: what is the value of `SaleInfo.SaleDate.Kind` ? try setting this to local using `salesInfo.SaleDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(salesInfo.SaleDate, DateTimeKind.Local);`

Comment: Thank You Wal, specifying the Kind property solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the value of `SaleInfo.SaleDate.Kind` ?

try setting this to Local using

```
salesInfo.SaleDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(salesInfo.SaleDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
```